# DCPcrypt : AES 128 bit support?

Tags: delphi

I recently installed DCPcrypt and I noticed that it has Rijndael support.

My question is :

1.Can I use the Rijndael chipher to decrypt an AES(128) stream ?
I noticed that the key size is set to 256 and I can't modify it in Object Inspector

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can modifying this but not in inspector i must change it on initialize :

> ```
>    DCP_rijndael1.Init(keyByteArray,128,nil); // initialize the cipher
> ```

The best sample for use it in the [demo](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/_media/opensource/dcpdemos.zip) .

i hope help you.